# Micronaut with Hibernate Spatial types deserialization

Tags: jackson, micronaut, micronaut-data, hibernate-spatial

The essence of the question is to serialize and deserialize the Geometry class from Hibernate Spatial in the Micronaut framework. This is how the field is represented in my entity.

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Point;
...
@Column(columnDefinition = "geometry")
private Point point;
...
```

This is how the field is represented in the Postgres database with PostGIS.

```
...
point geometry
...
```

There is an error when getting an existing record from the database

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1626)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations$FirstResultCollector.getFirst(HibernateJpaOperations.java:623)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations$FirstResultCollector.collect(HibernateJpaOperations.java:616)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations$FirstResultCollector.collect(HibernateJpaOperations.java:597)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.AbstractHibernateOperations.collectResults(AbstractHibernateOperations.java:365)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.AbstractHibernateOperations.collectFindOne(AbstractHibernateOperations.java:286)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations.lambda$findOne$2(HibernateJpaOperations.java:254)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.execute(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:145)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.executeRead(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:160)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.executeRead(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:150)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations.findOne(HibernateJpaOperations.java:252)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DefaultFindOptionalInterceptor.intercept(DefaultFindOptionalInterceptor.java:47)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DefaultFindOptionalInterceptor.intercept(DefaultFindOptionalInterceptor.java:34)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:83)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:143)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at com.example.domain.StoreRepository$Intercepted.findById(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.domain.StoreServiceImpl.getById(StoreServiceImpl.java:14)
    at com.example.domain.StoreController.getById(StoreController.java:13)
    at com.example.domain.$StoreController$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:371)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:594)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:303)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$executeRoute$14(RouteExecutor.java:659)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2508)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:371)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onSubscribe(ReactorSubscriber.java:50)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxJust.subscribe(FluxJust.java:68)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.handleRouteMatch(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:601)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:457)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler.channelRead0(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:147)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:99)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:102)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:224)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:109)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:202)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.channelRead(FlowControlHandler.java:164)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:346)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:318)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:440)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:788)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:287)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.fromBytes(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:138)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor.wrap(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:29)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.VarbinaryTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(VarbinaryTypeDescriptor.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:253)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3214)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.hydrateEntityState(Loader.java:1811)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1624)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:748)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowsFromResultSet(Loader.java:1047)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:998)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:967)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:357)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2868)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2850)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2682)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2677)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:540)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:400)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:218)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1459)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1649)
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1617)
    ... 103 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header: 30313031
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:958)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:392)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper$CustomObjectInputStream.<init>(SerializationHelper.java:299)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:218)
    ... 133 common frames omitted
...
```

Hibernate spatial the latest version (major 6), so I did not specify a special dialect for PostGIS.

Adding the com.bedatadriven:jackson-datatype-jts and org.n52.jackson:jackson-datatype-jts dependencies doesn't help.

Tried similarly creating a project on Spring Boot 3. There everything works without connecting third-party libraries for jackson besides spring-boot-starter-data-jpa.
As I see it, the problem lies in the objectMapper. On the Spring Boot project, objectMapper has some additional modules like Spring Geo Mixins (class GeoModule from org.springframework.data.geo).
Registering such a bean in Micronaut didn't help either. :(

I also tried adding my custom converter.

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class GeometryConverter implements AttributeConverter<Geometry, String> {
    private static final WKBWriter WRITER = new WKBWriter();
    private static final WKBReader READER = new WKBReader();
    
    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Geometry attribute) {
        return WKBWriter.toHex(WRITER.write(attribute));
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @Override
    public Geometry convertToEntityAttribute(String dbData) {
        return READER.read(WKBReader.hexToBytes(dbData));
    }
}
```

But it only works for receiving, and when I try to save a new entity to the database, it gives the following error

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:742)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations.lambda$persist$8(HibernateJpaOperations.java:326)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.execute(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:145)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.executeWrite(AbstractSynchronousStateTransactionManager.java:165)
    at io.micronaut.transaction.support.AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.executeWrite(AbstractSynchronousTransactionManager.java:155)
    at io.micronaut.data.hibernate.operations.HibernateJpaOperations.persist(HibernateJpaOperations.java:322)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DefaultSaveEntityInterceptor.intercept(DefaultSaveEntityInterceptor.java:45)
    at io.micronaut.data.runtime.intercept.DataIntroductionAdvice.intercept(DataIntroductionAdvice.java:83)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at io.micronaut.validation.ValidatingInterceptor.intercept(ValidatingInterceptor.java:143)
    at io.micronaut.aop.chain.MethodInterceptorChain.proceed(MethodInterceptorChain.java:137)
    at com.example.domain.StoreRepository$Intercepted.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.domain.StoreServiceImpl.save(StoreServiceImpl.java:22)
    at com.example.domain.StoreController.save(StoreController.java:18)
    at com.example.domain.$StoreController$Definition$Exec.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at io.micronaut.context.AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition$DispatchedExecutableMethod.invoke(AbstractExecutableMethodsDefinition.java:371)
    at io.micronaut.context.DefaultBeanContext$4.invoke(DefaultBeanContext.java:594)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.AbstractRouteMatch.execute(AbstractRouteMatch.java:303)
    at io.micronaut.web.router.RouteMatch.execute(RouteMatch.java:111)
    at io.micronaut.http.context.ServerRequestContext.with(ServerRequestContext.java:103)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.RouteExecutor.lambda$executeRoute$14(RouteExecutor.java:659)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDeferContextual.subscribe(FluxDeferContextual.java:49)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.subscribe(Flux.java:8660)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(FluxFlatMap.java:426)
    at io.micronaut.reactive.reactor.instrument.ReactorSubscriber.onNext(ReactorSubscriber.java:57)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.success(MonoCreate.java:172)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.RoutingInBoundHandler$4.doOnComplete(RoutingInBoundHandler.java:965)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor$1.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:136)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:178)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.processor.SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.doOnComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingProcessor.java:48)
    at io.micronaut.jackson.core.parser.JacksonCoreProcessor.doOnComplete(JacksonCoreProcessor.java:94)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.onComplete(SingleThreadedBufferingSubscriber.java:71)
    at io.micronaut.http.server.netty.jackson.JsonContentProcessor.doOnComplete(JsonContentProcessor.java:161)
    at io.micronaut.core.async.subscriber.CompletionAwareSubscriber.onComplete(CompletionAwareSubscriber.java:79)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.publishMessage(HandlerPublisher.java:383)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.flushBuffer(HandlerPublisher.java:470)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.publishMessageLater(HandlerPublisher.java:360)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.complete(HandlerPublisher.java:423)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.handlerRemoved(HandlerPublisher.java:418)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.callHandlerRemoved(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:1122)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.callHandlerRemoved0(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:637)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:477)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.remove(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:423)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.removeHandlerIfActive(HttpStreamsHandler.java:483)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.handleReadHttpContent(HttpStreamsHandler.java:319)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsHandler.java:282)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsServerHandler.channelRead(HttpStreamsServerHandler.java:134)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.extensions.WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.channelRead(WebSocketServerExtensionHandler.java:109)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:444)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageCodec.channelRead(MessageToMessageCodec.java:111)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.channelRead(HttpServerKeepAliveHandler.java:64)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:442)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:420)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:412)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.dequeue(FlowControlHandler.java:202)
    at io.netty.handler.flow.FlowControlHandler.read(FlowControlHandler.java:139)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:837)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.read(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:814)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher.requestDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:165)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.stream.HttpStreamsHandler$2.requestDemand(HttpStreamsHandler.java:273)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.receivedDemand(HandlerPublisher.java:556)
    at io.micronaut.http.netty.reactive.HandlerPublisher$ChannelSubscription.lambda$request$0(HandlerPublisher.java:494)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute$$$capture(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:566)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3279)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3914)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:645)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:282)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:317)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:329)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:122)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:756)
    ... 89 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "point" is of type geometry but expression is of type character varying
  Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
  Position: 42
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2676)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2366)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:356)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:496)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:413)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:190)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:152)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:61)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
    ... 107 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Can you please create an issue in Micronaut Data with a sample project? I can take a look.

Comment: Could you post more of the stacktrace, so we can see where in Hibernate the exception occurs?

Comment: Added a full exception stack trace. Also created an issue in Micronaut Data https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data/issues/2166